# PHPBB Add User Automatically When They Sign-up on the Main Website

Tags: php, curl, phpbb

I have a website that requires login and I've installed PHPBB to a subdomain. I want users to automatically register to the PHPBB forum when they register to the main page and I need to give them access to only specific forums so I need to give them forum permissions based on their choices on the register page. How can I achieve this?

I've tried sending requests to [ACP Add User Plugin](https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/extension/acp_add_user_2/) using cURL but it requires tokens so after some time token expires and I can't send any more requests.

Comment: You'd probably have to find a way to obtain a token, then. How are you getting a token currently?

Comment: I send the request on my browser and then I go to the network tab on developers console.

Comment: Well then you can see what your browser does when it makes the request, and try to write PHP/curl code which does the same thing, and get the token it returns.

Comment: phpbb do automatic registration with an ldap. But, I'm not sure you can do what you want without coding a plugin

Answer (score 1):

When you use your Browser to get the key, go into the developer tools, network tab, select the first http request, right click and choose copy as curl.

I would NEVER install Chrome on my PC. So here is a Firefox example.

[image: Developer Tools cop curl]

Then go to [Convert curl commands to PHP](https://curlconverter.com/php/)

And paste in the curl copied from your Browser.

So now you can go get a new token when ever you need a new one.